# SQL Count on Multiple Fields

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I'm not even sure if this is possible or whether I just need to write multiple queries.

I have a database table as follows:-

USER

- university_id
- gender

The output I'd like to achieve is as follows

```
| Uni  | Total Users | Male | Female
| Uni1 | 30          | 15   | 15
| Uni2 | 40          | 25   | 15
```

I would be grateful if you could let me know if this is possible to achieve in a single queries, or whether I should just use different queries for each result.

Thank you in advance.

Phill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can do it in a single query:

```
select
  UniversityId,
  count(*) as `Total Users`,
  sum(case when gender = 'male' then 1 else 0 end) as Male,
  sum(case when gender = 'female' then 1 else 0 end) as Female
from User
group by UniversityId
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7d16a/4